# SQL multi variable text input single column field

Tags: mysql

I want to convert an Excel search sheet to SQL.

text input box:  `Sam Tony Blair Arnold Palmer Tom`

Display Results:

```
Sam                      415 585-8855
Tony Blair               917 888-2222
Arnold Palmer            658 757-2222
Tom                      848 785-6635
```

Constraints: no punctuation to divide the names

Possible solution: code that can search every field for text variable?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit terse, some more details might help (table structure etc), but I think what you are looking to do is search each of the fields with each of the potential values.

You are going to need to split the text of the input box into strings to search for:

Sam Tony Blair need to get split into a list of strings, and a complex SQL statement will need to be built to search those strings in each of the potential fields.

Assuming that you have a field called "FirstName" and a field called "LastName", in a table called "Contacts" something like this would work:

```
select * From "Contacts" where 
FirstName like '%Sam%' or LastName like '%Sam%' or 
FirstName like '%Tony%' or LastName like '%Tony%' or 
FirstName like '%Blair%' or LastName like '%Blair%'
```

You will continue to build up the SQL for each term.

This isn't the best way to build a search engine.  You are much better off loading this into a dedicated search engine, but that might be out of scope for you.

Comment: The way my database is set up, the search field is just NAME. It will contain Tony Blair , or Sam , does not require two columns of first name and last name. Would the code be much simpler?